# 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, sections

Yes there are so many question on this title. But none solved my problem.
In my app am using sections in table view to show dropdown when clicked on them. And there is UIButton to add data and it takes user to another view to add.
After user adds data and press done I am using dismiss view controller to go back .
So now no of sections will be +1 with new data.
When user presses on the section now app quits with this error

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (35) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (34), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

my code is

```
NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(int i=0;i<username_rank.count;i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexx=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:btn.tag];
        [tempArr addObject:indexx];
    }

    [tournament_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tempArr withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

 *** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e7b7d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e22bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e7b7bea +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x000000010de75d5a -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
4   UIKit                               0x000000010fbca0dc -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 14140
5   UIKit                               0x000000010fbe0cf0 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 303
6   Sports Lion                         0x000000010d720c3f -[entertheden Btntap_expand:] + 447
7   UIKit                               0x000000010fa9ca8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
8   UIKit                               0x000000010fc0fe67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
9   UIKit                               0x000000010fc10143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
10  UIKit                               0x000000010fc0f263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
11  UIKit                               0x000000010ff84c52 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 10279
12  UIKit                               0x000000010fb0f48e -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
13  UIKit                               0x000000010fb106c4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
14  UIKit                               0x000000010fabbdc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
15  UIKit                               0x000000010fa95553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6dd301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6d322c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6d26e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6d20f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113250ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x000000010fa9af09 UIApplicationMain + 171
22  Sports Lion                         0x000000010d77050f main + 111
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111d4c92d start + 1
24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thanks

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Comment: OK, so the exception text explains what the actual problem is, yes?  You have changed 0 rows after calling `updateRowsBlahBlah`.  If you are adding the data to the model in another view controller which has since been dismissed then that isn't the write call to use, if you ask me.  Also your question talks about sections, but the calls/errors/etc seems to relate to rows.

Comment: Before presenting the another view controller no of sections was 34 and after coming back from the view controller the tableview will be updated with new data from the server which he added in the new view controller . So now there will be 35 sections with a new data.

Comment: @nandy : A temp fix can you change insertRowsAtIndexPaths and replace it with [tableView reloadData]

Comment: there when user click on any section then this error comes.

Comment: Sure @sandeep let me try. Thanks

Comment: Hoo @SandeepBhandari It works Thanks a lot ..... you are awesome

Comment: @nandy : I din say its an answer buddy :) Thats the worst thing to do to affect ur app performance :) But its just a temp fix :)

Comment: ho that I understood now its taking a bit can you suggest me to do anything

Comment: for that Ill need to see your code a little more buddy :) What is your data source for tableView ??? How are you updating it ???

Comment: The thing is I already said that am taking user to another view controller but that is taking to long can I know why.

Comment: Without seeing code I cant guess anything buddy :) Please post relevant code like what are you doing in your another view controller how are you informing your controller that data source changed and all those stuff

Answer (score -3):

You should reload the table view whenever there is a change in data source.
So you can call [yourTableView reloadData] method.

Comment: That will look horrible though, won't it.

Comment: @user3409280 : Its been suggested by me in comments atleast 20 mins before you did answer. Please read comments. I could have down voted your answer buddy

Comment: @SandeepBhandari You shouldn't downvote just because you think this user stole your idea.  It actually works (as confirmed by the OP) so it's not "wrong", which should be the only reason for downvoting.  Having said that I also downvote out of spite myself sometimes; we are only human.

Comment: @trojanfoe : I understand buddy :) Thats why I din down vote :) Just told him copying or posting the answer which is already there in comments or somebody else's answer isnt a great way to earn points :)

Comment: Actually it's perfectly acceptable.  The "buddy" thing wearing a bit thin though.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari there are many questions with the same answer but does it mean that all stole each other ideas. anyways i liked it that there are many others who thinks same as me :)